# Using an ODC file to link to a database

Tags: python, database

I have a 'data cube.odc' file that is being used to send information to an excel spreadsheet.

I want to use that same data with python to create an anomaly detection system.

Currently I'm trying to use pyodc, yet what I'm finding is the details inside the datacube.odc file are not the required details for using pyodc.

The cube file has these as details ,

```
</xml><xml id=msodc><odc:OfficeDataConnection
  xmlns:odc="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:odc"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
  <odc:Connection odc:Type="OLEDB">
   <odc:ConnectionString>
   Provider=MSOLAP.3;
   Password=#####;
   Persist Security Info=True;User ID=streams-bi01\#####User;
   Initial Catalog=Cube;
   Data Source=https://bi.streams.##.its:####/olap/####.dll;
   Location=https://bi.streams.##.its:####/olap/#####.dll;
   MDX Compatibility=1;
   Safety Options=2;
   MDX Missing Member Mode=Error
   </odc:ConnectionString>
   <odc:CommandType>Cube</odc:CommandType>
   <odc:CommandText>Cube</odc:CommandText>
  </odc:Connection>
 </odc:OfficeDataConnection>
</xml>
<style>
```

,

Is there a solution to this issue with the given details?

This is what I'm trying to execute with python,

```
import pyodc

cnxn = pyodbc.connect(
    DRIVER={https://bi.streams.vr.its:###/olap/####.dll};
                      SERVER=SQLSRV01;DATABASE=https://bi.streams.##.its:####/olap/####.dll;
                      UID=streams-bi01\####User;
                      PWD=#####)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

Comment: any luck solving this? Running into similar problems.